# Why does this work: "cp image.bin /dev/mapper/loop0p1"?

Tags: partition, cp, dd, loop-device

Why does this work?

```
cp image.bin /dev/mapper/loop0p1
```

`image.bin` is a partition image.

I have tried it and works, but why? Shouldn't a `dd` be used?

Comment: Are you sure you don't mean /dev/loop0p1?  There won't be a loop in /dev/mapper unless you have done some hacking around with `dmsetup`.

Comment: @psusi: loop partitions are mapped devices, they aren't there by default

Comment: @frostschutz, they are if you boot with the loop.max_parts argument, or you can use `partprobe` or `partx` to activate them otherwise.  There's no need to involve the device-mapper.

Comment: @psusi, thanks. It's `kpartx` that uses device mapper instead. I guess it doesn't really matter for a temporary loop device.

Answer (score 3):

GNU coreutils `cp` works because it was written that way. Writing to block devices isn't complicated, it's essentially the same operation as writing to a regular file.

However, you shouldn't use `cp` that way. You can do it if you're sure it's GNU coreutils, which works. But there are other flavours of `cp` around, for example `busybox cp` does not support writing to devices at all; it unlinks (deletes) the device node and creates a new file in its place instead.

`dd` is safer in that regard. It was made for writing to devices and brings the tools (bs, seek, skip, count, ...) you often need when dealing with devices. It should do the expected thing in all flavours of `dd`.

Comment: How can "cp be written that way" if "it's essentially the same operation"? Is leaving out a check for a block device and not exiting due to that "written that way"? 8-)  The busybox behaviour seems stupid to me. Is that POSIX compliant? You (may) change access rights by that. And if the target cannot be unlinked, does it fail then? :-/

Comment: Stupid or not, I just wanted to point it out.

Comment: That does sound like a bug in busybox...

Comment: How about `cat image.bin > /dev/mapper/loop0p1` in busybox?

Answer (score 2):

Your expectation differs from program / system design. What shall we say about that? :-)

"Everything is a file"...

You could run cp and/or dd through `strace -e trace=open` and will see that the syscall is the same for both regular files and block devices. If the syscall does not tell them apart, why should cp care?

Comment: Can you do the opposite? cp /dev/sdb1 ~/disk.iso

Comment: Yes. You can use `cp`, `dd` or even `cat` (and probably a few other commands).

Comment: @Guerrio Indeed. But usually `dd` is taken for that because it is more flexible. `cp` can copy whole "files" only.

Comment: This works in some shells: `< /dev/sdb1 > ~/disk.iso`.

Answer (score 2):

Well as far as I know, all that `cp` does is

- open the target file in write mode
- write the data from the source file to the target file (not sure about the chunk size though, but that's just details)

With normal files, this can result in either

- creating a new file that will grow with each write call
- Overwriting an existing file that will be overwritten:
  The first write call will erase the file's contents and put the new data in it.
  From that point on the file grows exactly like if it was a new one.

Now /dev/mapper/* are block devices (or to be specific, symbolic links to block devices). Those do have static file sizes. Therefore, if you open those files, each `write()` call will simply overwrite the n bytes of the target file you sent to it (assuming there's no `fseek()` call anywhere).

So, let's write our own poor-man's cp:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void usage() {fprintf(stderr, "Usage: cp <srcFile> <tgtFile>\n"); exit(1);}
void error(const char *msg) {fprintf(stderr, "Error: %s\n", msg); exit(2);}

void printPosAndSize(FILE *f) {
    off_t curPos = ftello(f);
    fseeko(f, 0, SEEK_END);
    off_t size = ftell(f);
    fseeko(f, curPos, SEEK_SET);
    printf("Pos: %llu,\tSize: %llu\n", curPos, size);
}

int main(int argc, const char *argv[]) {
    if (argc != 3) usage();

    const char *srcPath = argv[1];
    const char *tgtPath = argv[2];

    FILE *inFile = fopen(srcPath, "rb");
    FILE *outFile = fopen(tgtPath, "wb");

    printf("inFile: %s, outfile: %s\n", srcPath, tgtPath);

    if (!inFile) error("Couldn't open source file!");
    if (!outFile) error("Couldn't open target file!");

    while (!feof(inFile)) {
        char buff[2048];
        size_t count = fread(buff, 1, sizeof(buff), inFile);
        fwrite(buff, 1, count, outFile);
        printPosAndSize(outFile);
    }

    fclose(inFile);
    fclose(outFile);

    return 0;
}
```

This cp will write 2048 byte chunks from file1 to file2. If you just copy regular files, the output will look like that:

```
# copying to new file:
$ sudo ./cp /var/log/syslog /tmp/foo.txt 
inFile: /var/log/syslog, outfile: /tmp/foo.txt
Pos: 2048,      Size: 2048
Pos: 4096,      Size: 4096
Pos: 4949,      Size: 4949

# overwriting existing file:
$ sudo ./cp /var/log/syslog /tmp/foo.txt 
inFile: /var/log/syslog, outfile: /tmp/foo.txt
Pos: 2048,      Size: 2048
Pos: 4096,      Size: 4096
Pos: 4949,      Size: 4949
```

I'm running it twice to show you that it doesn't matter if the target file existed before opening it in write mode. As soon as you write to it, its contents get fully overwritten and the file size reflects that.

So, let's try something different:
    $ sudo ./cp /var/log/syslog /dev/null
    inFile: /var/log/syslog, outfile: /dev/null
    Pos: 0, Size: 0
    Pos: 2048,      Size: 0
    Pos: 974,       Size: 0

`/dev/null` is a character device. Those always have size 0. The output is simply written to them (e.g. to the serial port) and forgotten afterwards.

But let's get to your question: What happens if you write to a block device (**Caution! Executing this will make all the data on the device unreadable as it destroys the drive's meta information!** I've used an old USB drive for this demo)

```
$ sudo ./cp /var/log/syslog /dev/sdb
inFile: /var/log/syslog, outfile: /dev/sdb
Pos: 2048,      Size: 2003828736
Pos: 4096,      Size: 2003828736
Pos: 5306,      Size: 2003828736
```

The block file is simply opened at position 0 and overwritten byte by byte (without touching all the other data).

Comment: I don't get the sense of the last paragraph...

Comment: I think the last paragraph hints at some other very useful dd copying. Just one which has nothing to do with the OPs question.

Comment: @Hennes OK, now I got it. But what is surprising about that? Should cp pad the rest of the block device with zeroes or whatever? :-S

Comment: Sry, the last paragraph was a little confusing. I replaced it by some example code and some executions that should cover all the different target file types (regular file, character and block dev)